# How to disable hpet in linux

Tags: performance

I've recently just made the switch to Linux and is a complete noob at this. I want to disable hpet but can't find the option in my Alienware Bios, so I tried to disable it through terminal. After some research, I found out about “hpet=disable” and “nohpet” but don't know how apply these two commands. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why do you want to disable hpet?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find:

```
"quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
"quiet splash hpet=disable"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub
```